# Can't download contents of gopro on Linux Mint 18.1

Tags: usb, camera

I'm trying to download the contents of a gopro using Linux Mint 18.1 but I'm having trouble. The camera mounts automatically but when I access it via nemo there are some folders and no file. However, the camera shows that there are lots of files in it.

So I try to import everything using Shotwell but it fails with this message

> Unable to fetch previews from the camera: Could not claim the USB
>   device (-53)

Apparently this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bug/1400470) but the fix didn't work for me (which is to unmount the camera first and then start shotwell).

So I'm trying to do it with `gphoto2` using

```
gphoto2 --debug --debug-logfile=my-logfile.txt --get-all-files
```

but I also can't. If the camera is unmounted it doesn't fail but it just downloads a shortcut ascii file and no pictures.

If the camera is mounted then it fails with this message

```
*** Error ***              
An error occurred in the io-library ('Could not claim the USB device'): Could not claim interface 0 (Device or resource busy). Make sure no other program (gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor) or kernel module (such as sdc2xx, stv680, spca50x) is using the device and you have read/write access to the device.
*** Error (-53: 'Could not claim the USB device') ***
```

I have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to play my GoPro videos on linux mint 18.2, just take the memory card out of the phone and stick it in a card reader and plug it into the computer. That's it! 
I figured this out by accident. I bought a cheap camera that does work on linux, I switched the memory cards just to see what would happen and it worked. Just take the card out of the camera and you can play them as normal.